# How to design the service object with view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service-object

Foreword: maybe I misunderstand the conception of the service objects and should to design an another implementation. Thank you in advance.

---

I create the service object for a sms confirmations.
User must confirm his actions when:

- He submits a phone number (updates own profile);
- He confirms the transaction;
- He does other important action;

Here is the communication scheme:
[image]

Code:

**profile_controller:**

```
def update

  @profile.assign_attributes(profile_params)
  if @profile.valid?
    confirm = SmsConfirmationService.new({user: current_user,
                                          phone: profile_params["phone"],
                                          kind: :phone})
    confirm.confirm_phone
  else
    ...
  end

end
```

**sms_confirmation_service:**

```
class SmsConfirmationService

  attr_reader :status

  def initialize(params)
    @user = params[:user]
    @phone = params[:phone]
    @kind = params[:kind]
  end

  def create_pin
    pin = Pin.new(code: rand(0000..9999).to_s.rjust(4, "0"),
                  profile_id: @user.profile.id)
    pin.save

    send_sms(pin.code)
  end

  def send_sms(code)
    # call to SMS-provider API and check the status

    render_view
  end

  def render_view
    template = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})

    if @kind == :phone
      template.render(file: 'confirmation/confirm_phone')
    end
  end

end
```

I stuck on the render_view method. I get a 'Missing template profile/update', but according to logs, the template is rendered:

```
....
Rendered confirmation/confirm_phone.html.haml (6.7ms)
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "pins" ("code", "profile_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["code", 7811], ["profile_id", 7], ["created_at", "2016-08-26 15:45:02.751384"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-26 15:45:02.751384"]]
  (1.0ms)  commit transaction
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1070ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template profile/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:ru], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :haml, :jbuilder]}.
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Services are services--they don't have views. View-related stuff *calls* service objects.

Comment: Is there a different concept for such cases? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Such cases as what? Service objects, the way I understand them, are explicitly for moving functionality out of code not directly related to what's calling the objects. E.g., in a Rails controller, making calls to send SMS messages is a secondary concern to how the results of that SMS send is handled. Moving the SMS send itself into another class allows trivial testing of the controller itself (or whatever is using the SMS service object).